# return vacio con fetch a api

Tags: javascript, fetch

este es mi codigo el cual deberia retornarme informacion:

```
const endpoint = 'https://proyectfintech-production.up.railway.app/login'
var email = "jhonalmo23@gmail.com"
var password = "123"


var request = endpoint + '?email=' + email + '&password=' + password

fetch (request,{
    'mode':'no-cors'}
)
.then(request => request.text())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Pero el response en el navegador me muestra vacio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si usas el mode no-cors no puedes tener acceso al response

Comment: @Pipe si no lo uso me sale este error  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Debes agregar cors en el servidor. Si el servidor no esta bajo tu control, puedes implementar un servidor propio que obtenga la respuesta por ti, no puedes obtener la respuesta directo de tu pagina al servidor externo

Comment: El servidor es mio, ya implemente esto en el main de la api.
Muchas gracias crack

Comment: Con gusto. Saludos